# Is there a way to save Firebase data for later use in function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently using React and wish to retrieve data from my RealTime Database and save it in the variable: 'information' using the setInformation function from useState but when I run it, it still says that 'information' is null. I am sure I initialized Firebase correctly as when I write to the database it does show up, and the path in which I reference is also correct. I am not sure what I am doing wrong can someone help me please.

My Code:

```
    function retrieveData() {

        const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
        const curUserUID = curUser.uid
        const curDatabase = firebase.database()
        const [information, setInformation] = useState(null)
        
        console.log(curUserUID)
        curDatabase.ref('user/' + curUserUID).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
            setInformation(snapshot.val().information))
        })
        
        return(
        
          <div>
            <h1>{information.age}</h1>
          </div>
        
        )
```

console.log Outputs:

```
HSfF9HwtK2QaYfUp4bHlhedGuKD2
{age : "23", weight : "90", height : "180"}
```

My Database Structure:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "HSfF9HwtK2QaYfUp4bHlhedGuKD2" : {
      "information" : {
        "age" : "23",
        "weight" : "90",
        "height" : "180"
      }
    },
    "vXcWmZfLKwXbwUfdEudFrM1X0np1" : {
      "information" : {
        "age" : "29",
        "weight" : "87",
        "height" : "178"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "it still says that 'information' is null" Can you show what you mean by that? Who says what precisely?

Comment: I get an error when rendering the page, the error says: Cannot read property 'age' of null

Comment: So it seems from that that `snapshot.val().information` is `null`. Can you replace the schema of your data with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I just updated my original post with the actual schema.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you also update your question to `console.log(curUserUID)` right before `const curDatabaseRef = ...` and `console.log(snapshot.val())` right inside the callback? Please update the question with both the updated code and its output.

Comment: I have updated my question and removed the const curDatabaseRef as it isn't in my code I left it in by accident sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Can you now also show the output of the new `console.log` calls?

Comment: I have added a section in the original post for the outputs of the console.log calls

Comment: Huh... the value shows up fine. That means the problem is not in retrieving from Firebase, but in how you pass it to your renderer.  Note that this should typically be in a `useEffect` call.

Comment: Do you know what the useEffect call would look like as I don't have experience with useEffect

Comment: This has some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=react+useeffect+to+load+from+firebase